# Combine files using rake

Tags: concatenation, rake

I have a folder with some files named like this:

```
MonteCarlo_LHE_50-150_Tune_v14-v1.txt
MonteCarlo_LHE_50-150_Tune_v14_ext1-v1.txt
```

I want to concatenate the contents of these files into a single file with the common base name like this:

```
MonteCarlo_LHE_50-150_Tune_v14.txt
```

I know this can be done with:

```
cat inputfiles > outputfiles
```

However, I know it's possible to do this with Rakefile. I want to use rake because I have large number of input files like the one named above and I want to automate it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic version but if anyone has a much refined version please post:

```
def get_sample_names(substring)
    inputs = Dir.glob("inputs/test/*.txt").select {|x| x.include? substring}
    inputs = inputs.map{|x| File.basename(x).sub(".txt", ".txt")}
    inputs.push(substring+'.txt')
    return inputs
end

samples = Hash[
                "mc" => get_sample_names('MonteCarlo_LHE_50-150_Tune_v14'),
]

def concat_text_files(the_samples, numberofsamples)
    i = 0
    loop do
         sh "cat inputs/test/#{the_samples[i]} inputs/test/#{the_samples[i+1]} > inputs/test/#{the_samples[i+2]}"
         i += 3
         if i == 3*numberofsamples  
            break
         end
    end
end

task :concatText => concat_text_files(samples['mc'], numberofsamples=1)
```

The drawback of this solution is we have to define all the expected sample names before we run the rake.